# open layout | file size: 530x230 bleed included scale 1:1 / 1:10* - What is meant by that?

Tags: print-design, logo, export, print-production, file-format

I've received a description for a logo I have to export and don't understand what they mean. I tried to google it, but without success.

The description is written as follows:
"Demands are as follows (delivery of data ready for production will not be prooved): Resolution 70 dpi | **open layout** | document CMYK | indesign (pdf) | photoshop (tiff) | file size: 530x230 **bleed included scale 1:1 / 1:10** *"

I don't understand what is meant by open layout. Also does he mean by scale the color scale? And what are those numbers at the end?

Cheers!
Daniel

Comment: It's always best to ask the person providing the specification if you don't understand them.

Comment: Fully agree. My client is supposed to submit it until tomorrow and I think its too late for her to ask. But parallelly to posting this question I advised her to do it.

Comment: I've no idea about "open layout" - the rest are all pretty direct - 1:1 or 1:10 are accepted scale ratios - so 1:1 means it's drawn exactly to scale, 1:10 means 1" drawn =10" in final product. bleed included means that the dimension given does include any bleeds - I.E. if you want a design which bleeds to the edge of the trimmed medium, you're specifying a trim down - the actual design work cannot exceed 530x230 - they want CMYK and either a print-ready PDF or production-ready tiff - in other words so they can pre-press and print with minimal processing. But I'd have asked about "open layout"!

Comment: It sounds like you got these information through your client and she got it from someone else. Maybe she meant `open format` which are either the file format or the material dimensions before finishing steps like folding. Did you ever get to know ?